# Integration containing a complex number

Tags: calculus, integration, signal-processing, complex-integration

Folks,

Can I treat the complex number in the following integral:

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int\frac1{(1+jw)^2}dw$$

as a constant and move it outside of the integral, like this:

$$\frac1{j2\pi}\int\frac1{(1+w)^2}dw$$

Thanks!

Comment: When you "take it out" of the parenthesis $j$ gets squared, no?

Comment: Oh, yeah! It does, so it would just be -1.

Comment: Not only that, the "1" in the parenthesis should become $1/j$.

Comment: But you can't just pull it out like that. You'd need to factor it out of the denominator entirely, resulting in $$-\frac1{2\pi}\int\frac{dw}{(-j+w)^2}\,.$$

Comment: Okay, I see what you saying Ted. But I was planning to substitute w=tan theta, and then use the sec^2 theta trig identity. So, how should I get rid of the -j?

Comment: Okay, I figured this out! Thanks!

Comment: Just let $u = 1 + j w$.